# In what cases boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::read_some does not read all of the requested number of bytes?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

According to [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some.html) `basic_stream_socket::read_some` "…operation may not read all of the requested number of bytes". What does it actually mean?

Let's assume following scenario: we want to write a client which sends commands to a server and the server responds with lines of printable ASCII characters, each line ending with CRLF. Maximum line/response length is N bytes, including ending CRLF. We have the following code:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
std::array<char, N> inpbuff;
[…]
socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(inpbuff, N));
```

It's obvious that if the response length is shorter than N, `basic_stream_socket::read_some` "may not read all of the requested number of bytes". But are there other cases? What about issues with underlying TCP/IP such as [packet fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation) or delays due to [packet loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_loss)/[out-of-order delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_delivery)?

In other words, may I safely assume that the code above always reads the whole line/response? I have seen an implementation which makes such assumption but I am not sure if it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_some` reads *what is available*, until the buffer supplied is full.

What is *available* is dependent on the TCP stacks and intermediate hardware. In general the timing and fragmentation of TCP packets can NOT be relied on.

So, so code that does rely on it is probably flawed¹.

The good news is that the docs you quoted go on and tell you how fix it:

> The read_some operation may not read all of the requested number of bytes. Consider using the [read](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read.html) function if you need to ensure that the requested amount of data is read before the blocking operation completes.

Let me add that there is also another, more highlevel, *composed read operation* that you can often use to great effect: [`async_read_until`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until.html) or [`read_until`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until.html)

Comment: Well, I didn't write it explicitly, but server responses have variable length, where maximum length is N. So `read` does not solve my "problem". However `read_until` looks veeery promising.